# CSSFriendly issue just after publishing to web server

Tags: asp.net, css, menu, treeview

I created a website and used css friendly adapters for Menu, TreeView and GridView, all was correct, but after publishing it to my great web server, the menus and treeviews didn't load and there is just some bullets!

Here is my work: http://jds.cot.ir (dead link)

Left side I have a menu which did not load.

Comment: I viewed the html source, all are correct, and classes are visible and the style.css has been loaded, I don't know why it does not work.

Comment: what are the datasources for your controls? Are they binding to a database? If so, have you copied across your database etc?

Comment: For anyone still following this, there is a compile issue with App_Browsers and the .Net 3.5 or prior runtimes and VS2010. It will compile all other elements to the prior runtime but App_Browser.dll to 4.0 ... delete /bin/App_browsers.dll and it should be fine. This may not be the explicit cause you have, but it might just help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and the solution, I have an error loading one css file:

```
<link href="/WebResource.axd?d=FmPs0x8PbK0cHdhnI4N-J7cB33HdEr5UOoA_QzdIwqZdeINM8Kod5dxru5SzZMkL0&amp;t=633820044382031250" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and the content of this css was an error titled:

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: utcDate
```

I changed my pc date to one month ago and rebuilt my solution, and upload it again.

And every thing is correct. ;)

Comment: I just had this happen this evening while devloping, apparently due to the time change!!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy over the **App_Browsers** folder? I'd check you copied all files over and, if you can, restart the application pool (touching web.config should achieve this).

Comment: this folder exists, whould I restart the application pool? if yes, how? Do you mean via web.config, I can restart application pool?

Comment: I restarted the application by copying app_offilne.htm and requesting the url and renaming the file and again requesting the web site, but it is not correct yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting precompiled.config from the root of the web app on the server.  That did it for me.  Haven't really looked into what the pros and cons are.  Looks like the publisher's precompilation doesn't take into account the control adapters for some reason.  I just ran into this in VS2010 beta 2.